# Failed to read SQLite-net.dll during debugging symbols

Tags: android, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I try build application using xamarin forms in visual studio and deploy on android emulator this warning appears.

> Failed to read 'G:\ApkiC-Sharp\GNote\GNote\GNote.Android\obj\Debug\android\assets\SQLite-net.dll' with debugging symbols. Retrying to load it without it. Error details are logged below. GNote.Android

Details Bellow:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning     Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolFileException: Symbol file `G:\ApkiC-Sharp\GNote\GNote\GNote.Android\obj\Debug\android\assets\SQLite-net.dll.mdb' does not match assembly
>      at Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolFile.ReadSymbolFile(String mdbFilename, Guid assemblyGuid)
>      at Mono.Cecil.Mdb.MdbReaderProvider.GetSymbolReader(ModuleDefinition module, String fileName)
>      at Mono.Cecil.Cil.DefaultSymbolReaderProvider.GetSymbolReader(ModuleDefinition module, String fileName)
>      at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModule(Image image, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(Disposable`1 stream, String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.ReadAssembly(String file)  GNote.Android

How can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: You could read this : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98182/failed-to-read-sqlite-net-dll-with-debugging-symbols

Comment: I have seen it but didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:
Right click your android project
Properties -> Android Options -> drop down "Linking" to None.

It will include the symbols on package, but will increase your app size.

I'm trying to find another better solution, but this works for now.

Comment: Can you post a print of your Android Options screen?

Comment: i was thinking you're trying to build it in release mode.
You tried to delete bin, obj, clean project and rebuild?
You can try to set no one Debugger too, i always work like that.

Comment: Are all your project references with the same sqlite nuget package version? Check it on Nuget - Solution, Consolidate tab.

Comment: If I create brand new project and add only sqlite-net-pcl, this warning appear. I followed yours solution but didn't help.

Comment: well, if it's only a warning, don't bother with it after all.
I've solved my problem that was an error with these solutions:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/285626#Comment_285626

Comment: Thank you for try.