# Xamarin Android, MobileCenter and SQLite:

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I have a Xamarin project that it is working well. To have some logs, I added `MobileCenter` but now I receive an `java code 2`.

I read those posts:

- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98182/failed-to-read-sqlite-net-dll-with-debugging-symbols
- [Failed to read SQLite-net.dll during debugging symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912104/failed-to-read-sqlite-net-dll-during-debugging-symbols/44938810#44938810)

but without success. I removed and cleaned `bin`, `obj` and `packages` folders. I checked all package versions. The problem is still there. For `UWP` and `iOS` everything is working fine. Also, I tried to downgrade SQLite but nothing. The project is working again only if I remove MobileCenter, clean `bin`, `obj` and rebuild.

In detail, the error is like:

```
No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning : Failed to read 'C:\Projects\er\LifeInTheUK\LifeInTheUK\LifeInTheUK\LifeInTheUK.Android\obj\Debug\android\assets\SQLite-net.dll' with debugging symbols. Retrying to load it without it. Error details are logged below.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning : Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolFileException: Symbol file `C:\Projects\er\LifeInTheUK\LifeInTheUK\LifeInTheUK\LifeInTheUK.Android\obj\Debug\android\assets\SQLite-net.dll.mdb' does not match assembly
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning :    at Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolFile.ReadSymbolFile(String mdbFilename, Guid assemblyGuid)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning :    at Mono.Cecil.Mdb.MdbReaderProvider.GetSymbolReader(ModuleDefinition module, String fileName)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning :    at Mono.Cecil.Cil.DefaultSymbolReaderProvider.GetSymbolReader(ModuleDefinition module, String fileName)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning :    at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module, ReaderParameters parameters)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning :    at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModule(Image image, ReaderParameters parameters)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning :    at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(Disposable`1 stream, String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning :    at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning :    at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning :    at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.ReadAssembly(String file)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668,3): warning : Name cannot begin with the '$' character, hexadecimal value 0x24.
```

I changed the project settings and I enabled `multidex` but in this case another error occurs.

> Expecting class path separator ';' before
>   '\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\lib\shrinkedAndroid.jar' in
>   argument number 8
>
> File: CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST

[image: Error with multi-dex]

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: What SQLite-net nuget are you using?

Comment: sqlite-net-pcl 1.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Move the **Android SDK** to path without spaces and special symbols.
Move the SDK from 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ to C:\android\android-sdk\

Then, change the Android SDK path in Xamarin settings in VS to the new path (Tools - Options - Xamarin - Android Settings - Android SDK Location)

Answer (score 0):

Move the Android SDK to a path without spaces and special symbols. Move the SDK from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ to some other location but make sure there are no spaces in between.

Then, change the Android SDK path in Xamarin settings in VS to the new path (Tools - Options - Xamarin - Android Settings - Android SDK Location)

And then turn on MultiDex from your current project properties.

And you will be ready to go..